# Compiling perl on windows

Tags: perl, compilation

I am trying to compile perl(5.12.3) from source on windows(64 bit windows 2008 R2) using visual studio 10 )64 bit compiler.

Following configurations were done done:

Configure visual to compile 64 bit perl: 
 vcvarsall.bat x64
Changes in makefile:
uncommented: 
CCTYPE      = MSVC90
Set the value for MSVCDIR
On doing a make I am getting following error message:

```
..\miniperl.exe -I..\lib bin\exetype.pl ..\wperl.exe WINDOWS
'x' outside of string in unpack at bin\exetype.pl line 39.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '..\miniperl.exe' : return code '0xff'
Stop.
```

Please help me to understand what is missing.

I have tried with visual studion 13, but got same error.

Comment: I'd say you're missing the installers for Strawberry Perl. Get them at http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html .

Comment: I am not installing strawberry perl but trying to compile perl from source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a couple of fixes:

1. Set CCTYPE = MSVC60
2. Quote "$offset" on line 37.

It's a known bug that might be fixed on newer versions.

Comment: I have tried this also. This gives foPE header not found at bin\exetype.pl line 41.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '..\miniperl.exe' : return code '0xff'
Stop.llowing error message:

Comment: Try changing $(MINIPERL) to $(PERLEXE) in the make file.